# JAXB How to marshal an element both optional or nillable

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to marshal an element which can be null and in some cases should be not written in the final XML at all, in some other cases I should specify that it is nillable.

Consider the following example

```
<root>
    <element>
        <sub1>Whatever1</sub1>
        <sub2 xsi:nil="true"/>
    </element>
    <element>
        <sub1>Whatever2</sub1>
        <sub2>Not empty</sub2>
    </element>
    <element>
        <sub1>Whatever3</sub1>
    </element>
</root>
```

The element "sub2" is the one I'm having trouble with.

From my understanding I can easily achieve the first 2 cases with the Element class declared as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "element", propOrder = {
        "sub1",
        "sub2",
})
public class Element {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String sub1;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String sub2;
    //...
}
```

To obtain the last two instead, I would do:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "element", propOrder = {
        "sub1",
        "sub2",
})
public class Element {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String sub1;
    @XmlElement(required = false) //I could omit it entirely
    public String sub2;
    //...
}
```

Is there a way to obtain both?

I'm forced to Java 6 / JAXB 2.1.10.

Thank you.

Comment: Your pojo can understand both the type of xml elements. What are you trying that is not working? Do you want to "generate" xml in two format, or read xml in the given format? Using your pojo I can unmarshal your provided xml correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have elements which are both not required and nillable. There are a few things you need to do to make this work:

1. Make the field a `JAXBElement<String>` instead of `String`.
2. Create an `ObjectFactory` class with a factory method.
3. Put `@XmlElementDecl` on the factory method in the `ObjectFactory` and `@XmlElementRef` on the field in class `Element`.

Example:

Make the field a `JAXBElement<String>` with an `@XmlElementRef` annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "element", propOrder = {"sub1", "sub2"})
@XmlRootElement
public class Element {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String sub1;

    @XmlElementRef(name = "sub2", required = false)
    public JAXBElement<String> sub2;

    // ...
}
```

Create an `ObjectFactory` class with a factory method, with an `@XmlElementDecl` annotation. Note that the namespace and name of the `@XmlElementRef` and `@XmlElementDecl` annotation are the same:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "sub2")
    public JAXBElement<String> createSub2(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<>(new QName(null, "sub2"),
                                 String.class, Element.class, value);
    }
}
```

Marshalling example 1: Have a value for `sub2`:

```
ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();

Element element = new Element();
element.setSub1("one");
element.setSub2(objectFactory.createSub2("two"));

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class, Element.class);

Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(element, System.out);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element>
    <sub1>one</sub1>
    <sub2>two</sub2>
</element>
```

Marshalling example 2: No element at all in the XML:

```
Element element = new Element();
element.setSub1("one");
// Leave the field sub2 set to null
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element>
    <sub1>one</sub1>
</element>
```

Marshalling example 3: Create an element with the value `null` which will appear as an XML element which is set to `nil`:

```
Element element = new Element();
element.setSub1("one");
element.setSub2(objectFactory.createSub2(null));
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<element>
    <sub1>one</sub1>
    <sub2 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</element>
```

Comment: This would be the perfect answer for Java 7 and JAXB 2.2 or greater. But unfortunately I'm forced to Java 6 / JAXB 2.1.10. I'm trying to make it work for Java 6 too... I'll let you know if it is possible with a few modifications here and there.

Comment: The solution required a couple of changes for Java6 and JAXB 2.1 but is overall correct and worked pretty well. In particular, the XmlElementRef annotation had to change to `@XmlElementRef(name = "sub2", type = JAXBElement.class)`. the XmlElementDecl in the ObjectFactory to `@XmlElementDecl(name = "sub2", scope = Element.class)` and the type of its returned value explicitly written as `return new JAXBElement<String>(...)`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Jesper Jesper, you seem having a good insight into XML and Java - could you please have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67823414/2886891