# How to globally configure spring-ws / spring-boot-starter-web-services to serialize also empty (null) elements without modifying the serialized class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, serialization, marshalling, spring-ws

How to **globally** configure `spring-ws` / `spring-boot-starter-web-services` to serialize also empty (`null`) elements?

I cannot modify the serialized classes themselves, so I **cannot** add `nillable = true` such as

```java
public class Response {
    @XmlElement(name = "FirstName", required=true, nillable = true)
    private String firstName;
}
```

I want to have **all** the empty elements **present** (in any form, but present) in the response even if they are `null`, such as

```xml
<Response>
    <FirstName whatever-attribute-here/> <!-- anything here, just the element should be present here even if it is not set in the object -->
</Response>
```

Once again, I **cannot** modify the `Response` class and it does **not** contain the `nillable = true` attributes.

My motivation is that I am to implement the response mapping and I want to have a quick check (during the development) that I have not omitted any of the tens of elements. Setting all omitted elements manually to an empty string (or rather something more reasonable) is already what I want to achieve, it's the *goal* and not the *way* :)

I was trying to search the answer but all the results take me to the modification of the XML class itself or to setting the elements to an empty string. I believe there might be a nice global switch :)

In **JSON**, there **is** an analogical global switch: I can set globally (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-null-fields) either

```java
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.ALWAYS); // properties are always included, independent of value of the property
```

or

```java
mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL); // only properties with non-null values are to be included
```

Comment: Even if you could, adding `nillable = true` would not get you what you want. I don't think there is an easy way to get what you want (empty elements for `null` values automatically). If you set the field `firstName` to `""` (empty string, not `null`) in your object you should get an empty XML element.

Comment: @Jesper I believe that adding `nillable=true` would cause that the marshaller to generate elements with `nil` which is good enough. I just want to have **each element** somehow present in the response to see all of them - and to be able to quickly check which of them I forgot to map. I have an XML with tens of elements, not mine :(

Comment: @Jesper As for setting the element to an empty string, this will not help me. My motivation is that I want to have a fast control (during development and testing) which elements I forgot to map into the response :) Identifying all the missing fields and setting them to an empty string (or to something reasonable) is what I want to **achieve**, it's the *goal* and not the *way* :)

Comment: Yes, using `nillable=true` would make it output elements with `xsi:nil="true"` for elements with no value. So, you want to use this to generate sample XML output for development. One idea: write some code that fills your Java objects with dummy values, by inspecting them recursively via reflection, and then marshal it to XML.